# How to write a function which can return two integers?

Tags: arrays, c, function

*(I was able to solve the previous problem with the output of the array, everything worked out)*.

I have here a piece of code for which I would like to write a function to shorten the code. But I don't know how to do it, since, apparently, it would need to return two values and I do not know how to do it...

Or should I break this action into two different functions?

Or it is better to leave the code in this form?

```
  int a2x = 0;
  int m2x = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (x[i] > 0) {
      a2x = a2x + x[i];
    }
    if (x[i] < 0) {
      m2x++;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("a2x %5d \n", a2x);
  printf("m2x %5d \n", m2x);
  int a2y = 0, m2y = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (y[j] > 0) {
      a2y = a2y + y[j];
    }
    if (y[j] < 0) {
      m2y++;
    }
  }
  printf("a2y %5d \n", a2y);
  printf("m2y %5d \n",m2y);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can have the function with this return type:

```
struct ReturnType
{
    int a2y;
    int m2y;
};
```

This type reflects that it is a pair of values, not two instances of the same value. I.e. it is a X and an M, not two Xs and not two Ms. It also behaves like a copyable variable, like returning a single int.

Comment: Why would you ever create a structure of 2 int instead of using an array?

Comment: Whenever the values seem to be a pair of non-identical semantics. It is not "X twice" or "M twice", it is "an X and an M". @Davide

Comment: @Davide *Why would you ever create a structure of 2 int instead of using an array?*  Because you can return a structure.  You can't return an array.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. ;-) I resisted the temptation to answer on that angle.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You can return a pointer to the first element of the array. If you don't like to call it "array" it's fine, as long as you are aware that returning that pointer is equivalent to what would be returning an array.

Comment: What would that pointer point to after the function was left? In case of you answer with option III from your answer, how would you support those who use it with not forgetting to deallocate it? @Davide

Comment: @Davide The problem with returning a pointer to an array is you either have to make the array static which breaks thread safety, create a new array dynamically which means the caller has to dispose of it, or have the caller pass you a pointer to the array (which you covered in your answer).  When it's finally translated to machine instructions, returning a structure or passing the address of an array are likely all but identical performance-wise so at that point it's a style/preference/clarity/O&M issue which makes it very context-dependent.

Comment: Both of you. I think that is a discussion actually worth of a separate question. Davide, would you like to create one (checking for duplicates of course). I think at a separate question the discussion might be less burdened by the siutation between two answerers. Especially since I believe my comments are not completly free of defense/attack and we could delete all of them. If you agree I would like to use Andrews input to improve my answer, but I want Davide to confirm it is not attacking the other answer.

Comment: All right, anyway the semantic purpose of the structure is a good enough reason to use a struct rather than an array.

Comment: If you like you Davide use Andrews input, to discuss the array option. It would make your answer more insightful and I'd not have to discuss an option you proposed. I would feel better that way.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you what I believe are the 3 easiest options you have:

**I)** Print the result inside the function.

In this way not only you don't need to return the variables, but you can also declare them directly inside the function.

**II)** Pass the variables by reference.

In this way the function can actually change their value, so you don't need to return anything.

**III)** Allocate an array storing the values that you want to return, and return the array.

In this way you can return as many values as you want.

Edit: As suggested by Andrew Henle in the comments to Yunnosch's answer: "returning a structure or passing the address of an array are likely all but identical performance-wise so at that point it's a style/preference/clarity/O&M issue which makes it very context-dependent."

And since, as Yunnosch pointed out, with a structure you can give a different meaning to each element, using a structure is more appropriate in your case.

Comment: If you helpfully discuss the array option (with you-know-which details) and explain it convincingly I would upvote.

Comment: I don't want to use other people words, but anyway the takeaway is that using an array is equivalent to using a structure, but with a structure you can give a different meaning to each value. So in the OP case a structure is more appropriate. But since it's not so obvious to use a structure rather an array, you should add something about it in your answer.

Comment: You surely can use Andrews input. Just mention the name in the answer (it makes a good impression, I tried often). Maybe even write a comment like "Andrew, I assume it is Ok to improve my answer with your input." so that they notice. I really do not want to write something into my answer which reads like "I recommend not to use the option proposed in the other answer." In your answer the same things would read like a clean professional discussion, i.e. be good.

Comment: C does not support passing anything by reference, i think you mean passing by pointer.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Strictly speaking you are right. But to a large probability, most C programmers understand "via pointer" when they read "by reference". Without a hickup.

Comment: I miss the point about allocating and potential need for the caller to free.

Answer (score -1):

There is technically a other way not mentioned before: Pass it in a larger integer type:

```
#include <limits.h>

#define HIGHEST_UINT_BIT ((UINT_MAX>>1)+1)
#define HIGHEST_ULLINT_BIT ((ULLONG_MAX>>1)+1)
#if HIGHEST_ULLINT_BIT/HIGHEST_UINT_BIT/HIGHEST_UINT_BIT<2
  #error "unsigned long long int not large enough to hold 2 int variables"
#endif

//returns the integer a in higher half of the returning long long int
//and the integer b in the lower half of the returning long long
unsigned long long int foo(void)
{
  int a=42;    //set a to any integer value you like
  int b=0x42;  //same for b

  //pack a and b into the return value
  //<<(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT) shifts a to the higher half of r
  unsigned long long int r=((unsigned long long)a)<<(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT);
  r|=(unsigned)b;

  return r;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long int r=foo();
  //extract a and b from r
  int a=r>>(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT);
  int b=r&UINT_MAX;

  printf("a is %i (0x%X) b is %i (0x%X)\n",a,(unsigned)a,b,(unsigned)b);
  return 0;
}
```

But you should never use this method. Because it is not scalable to more variables, it only works when there is a integer type which is 2 times as large or larger, it only works for integers and it is a hack. Better use the pass by pointer method mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: It made sense to explain why one ""*[...] should never use this method.*".